# Cloudera Manager Rest API update service config

Tags: rest, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-manager

I was wondering if anyone could help me understand how to update a service running in cloudera manager with the REST API.

I've been going through the docs, and am trying to find a way to update some yarn configurations, but the docs are a little unclear.
[https://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v10/path__clusters_-clusterName-*services*-serviceName-_config.html](https://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v10/path__clusters_-clusterName-_services_-serviceName-_config.html)

I feel like I am close, but here is what I have so far:

```
curl -X PUT \
     -u <admin_username>:<admin_password> \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '{"yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb":4696}' \
     http://<CM_HOST>:7180/api/v10/clusters/spark-2/services/CD-YARN-rrOCWOpV/config
```

However, I'm getting a response saying:

```
{
  "message" : "Unrecognized property: 'yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb'"
}
```

The service name `CD-YARN-rrOCWOpV` was identified in the list of services from:

```
http://<CM_HOST>:7180/api/v10/clusters/spark-2/services/
```

From which I could see the result:

```
{
    "name" : "CD-YARN-rrOCWOpV",
    "type" : "YARN",
    ....
}
```

Thank you!!

### EDIT:

It looks like I was writing to the wrong location. What was needed was to write to role configuration (in this case it was the yarn `RESOURCEMANAGER` role).

After querying the roles, I was able to identify the name of the RESOURCEMANAGER role as `CD-Y76ddf83d-RESOURCEMANAGER-45344d25a0e70b3b594d08b277a10937`

And then updated the json object to match the object which is found from querying: `http://<CM_HOST>/api/v10/clusters/spark-2/services/CD-YARN-rrOCWOpV/roles/CD-Y76ddf83d-RESOURCEMANAGER-45344d25a0e70b3b594d08b277a10937/config?view=full`:

```
curl -X PUT \
     -u <admin_username>:<admin_password> \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '{"items": [{"name" : "yarn_scheduler_maximum_allocation_mb", "value":"4696"}]}' \
     http://<CM_HOST>/api/v10/clusters/spark-2/services/CD-YARN-rrOCWOpV/roles/CD-Y76ddf83d-RESOURCEMANAGER-45344d25a0e70b3b594d08b277a10937/config
```

Was able to get a successful response:

```
{
  "items" : [ {
    "name" : "resource_manager_java_heapsize",
    "value" : "472907776"
  }, {
    "name" : "yarn_scheduler_maximum_allocation_mb",
    "value" : "4696"
  }, {
    "name" : "yarn_scheduler_maximum_allocation_vcores",
    "value" : "2"
  } ]
```

Thank you again!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct attribute is yarn_scheduler_maximum_allocation_mb

Comment: Thank you for your response @jedijs. Unfortunately, that didn't work, same error `unrecognized property`. I tried a few different variations, without success.

Comment: Can you try with cm putting your value in this field? And activating cm debug, after you can view the call into cm server logs.

Comment: Thank you! After some playing around it turns out that you were right. The correct attribute is `yarn_scheduler_maximum_allocation_mb`. I needed to push the change into the RESOURCE_MANAGER role, and I had to replicate the structure of the config which you get from querying the role config. I'll edit my answer with the correct syntax. Thank you